# MySQL using JOIN and reports

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

So, I've got a mysql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT rewards.name, redemptions.points, redemptions.value
FROM rewards
INNER JOIN redemptions ON rewards.id = redemptions.reward_id;
```

The problem is that it spits out a table like this:

```
-----------------------------
| Reward 1 |  500   |  30   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 1 |  500   |  30   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 1 |  500   |  30   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 2 |  100   |  10   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 2 |  100   |  10   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 3 |  250   |  20   |
-----------------------------
```

and so on. Ideally, what I would actually like it to do is to only list each one once, but sum certain columns. So for example, it would look something like this:

```
-----------------------------
| Reward 1 |  500   |  90   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 2 |  100   |  20   |
-----------------------------
| Reward 3 |  250   |  20   |
-----------------------------
```

Where it is summing the third column, but listing the first two columns just once. I thought maybe a union would do it because I know it ignores duplicates, but I don't think it works while using unions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM`, and remember to add `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT rewards.name, redemptions.points, SUM(redemptions.value)
FROM rewards
INNER JOIN redemptions ON rewards.id = redemptions.reward_id
GROUP BY rewards.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.name, b.points, SUM(b.value)
FROM    rewards a
        INNER JOIN redemptions b
            ON a.id = b.reward_id
GROUP   BY a.name, b.points
```